# How to hide aws cer get-login-password output

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

I am using AWS(CLI v2) ECR login command in Jenkins pipeline as below where the password is getting printed to stdout when my bash env is set in -v mode.

```
            steps {
                    sh '''#!/bin/bash
                        set -xv
                        docker login --username AWS --password $(aws ecr get-login-password) $(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text).dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
                        docker push "${imageTag}"
                        docker logout $(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text).dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
                        '''
            }
```

Any better secure way to do this?

Comment: As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/getting-started-cli.html#cli-authenticate-registry) use `aws ecr get-login-password --region region | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Stdin option is not supported in latest docker cli version